# Signalling end of file in an HTTP server

Tags: c, http, http-headers

I'm writing a simple HTTP server in C. I've managed to bind, listen, and accept a connection. I'm trying to send a simple 404:

```
#define sends(socket, s) send(socket, (s), strlen((s)), 0)

void send_not_found(int socket)
{
  sends(socket, "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n");
  sends(socket, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
  sends(socket, "Server: brandonisawesome\r\n");
  sends(socket, "\r\nnot found");
}

void handle_request(void* param)
{
  int sock = *((int*)param);

  send_not_found(sock);
  close(sock);
}
```

This results in firefox giving me `The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.` Firebug tells me the request was sent:

http://puu.sh/5HDOl.png

In fact, "not found" displays for a quarter of a second before firefox tells me the connection was reset. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, when I do a hard refresh it shows up fine. It's only when I do a normal refresh that I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `Content-Length:`, and `Content-Type:` would be a good idea too.
For "not found" `Content-Length: 9` would be correct I think.

Comment: But I'm sending HTTP/1.0. Doesn't that mean I can just close the connection?

Comment: Content-Length works for me, but I've read that it's more of a hint than part of the protocol, and I've seen plenty of sites not send it. i don't want to have to calculate the length. How can I avoid using this?

Comment: @Brandon "A valid Content-Length field value is required on all HTTP/1.0 request messages containing an entity body." [HTTP/1.0 docs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#Content-Length). I don't know about avoiding including it.